# Parsing Strings ( .crt files )

Tags: bash, parsing, shell, scripting

Base Knowledge : I have a .crt file ( certification authoritie file ) and he is composed of many fields but in one line that resumes this question i have this :

```
    Certificate:
       ...(alot of stuff before)...
       Subject: C=US, ST=Maryland, L=Pasadena, O=Brent Baccala,
                OU=FreeSoft, CN=www.freesoft.org/emailAddress=baccala@freesoft.org
       Subject Public Key Info:
          ...(alot of stuff after)
```

and i need to parse the file to populate a .csv file and i have that done the problem that i need help is, i need to get the field:

```
CN=www.fresoft.org
```

but when i get this kind of CN=...(Value instead of the ...) with alot of slashes i get a error in the parsing like the raw string is:

```
CN=foo/bar/the/hell/emailAddress=blablabla
```

and i need only:

```
foo/bar/the/hell
```

and for a moment i got that in the correct column but when i dont have the emailAddress something just fail in my parsing and i then get in my CN .csv column the information wrong instead of

```
|CN|
foo/bar/the/hell
```

i get:

```
|CN|
OU=FreeSoft, foo/bar/the/hell.
```

I have this code doing the CN parsing:

```
#!/bin/bash

subject_line=$(echo $cert | grep -o "Subject:.*Subject Public Key Info")

cn=$(echo $subject_line | grep -o "CN=.*" )

if [ $(echo $cn | grep -c ".*email.*") -gt 0 ]; then
    end_cn=$(echo $cn | grep -b -o emailAddress)
    end_cn_idx=$(echo $end_cn | grep -o .*:)
    final_end_cn=${end_cn_idx:0:-1}
    common_name=${cn:3:$final_end_cn-4}

    echo $common_name

else
    end_cn=$(echo $cn | grep -b -o "Subject Public Key Info")
        end_cn_idx=$(echo $end_cn | grep -o .*:)
        final_end_cn=${end_cn_idx:0:-1}
        common_name=${cn:3:$final_end_cn-5}

        echo $common_name
fi
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this might work:

```
CN=$(openssl x509 -in /path/to/your.crt -noout -subject |
       sed -r 's|.*CN=(.*)|\1|; s|/[^/]*=.*$||')
```

It'd be easier to do this in Perl, though, because unlike `sed` Perl can do non-greedy matches:

```
CN=$(openssl x509 -in /path/to/your.crt -noout -subject |
       perl -ne 'print "$1" if m|.*CN=(.*?)(?:/[^/]*?=.*)?$|')
```

Comment: but this dont work if i dont have a email  address after the CN= right ?

Comment: Yes. If that part is optional, you'll have to remove it first. I updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: hi sorry to ask but is it possible to make a array on email like:
if after CN=blabla/bla exists ["emailAddress=", "OU=", "CT=", etc]  then parse only until the email or Ou or CT etc .
In  a way  that doesnt matter whatever would appear after the CN=blablabla/blabla ... the parse  would be always correct like:
i give him the CN=blablabla/bla/OU=YEs/emailAddress=you@you.com
and i would get only:
blablablabla/bla
or if i givem him CN=blablabla/bla/CT=URtest/OU=YES/emailAddress=you
i would  get:
blablablabla/bla

Comment: sometimes on imported .crt files i get CN=blabla/bla/emailAddress and sometimes i have CN=blablabla/bla/OU=youknow/email and then my .csv parser do this on the CN column:
CN!
blablabla/bla/OU=youknow 
because the regular expression goes all the way from the "CN=" until he finds the emailAddress= instead of stopping in the next paramenter that is only 5 options either OU or U or CT or Email or L soo if i make a array with that i know that he gonna find for any of that paramenters and if he finds it its all good .

Comment: Well to be very clear would be from "CN=" until the next "=" but the "=" is always with 2 Characters that i dont need that could be the "emailAddress" or "OU" etc. 

In resume 
from CN=blabla/bla/OU= 
i want : blablabla/bla .

or
from CN=blablabla/bla/T=something 
i want still only the " blablabla/bla

or if for final example ( and this is only to make a different example):

from : CN=blablabla/bla/emailAddress=something
want : blablabla/bla

Comment: Being very clear about these things usually helps. Check the updated commands in my answer.